# Is $F:= \{X\}$ a filter over $X$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, filters

Given a nonempty set $X$, define a family of sets $F$ over $X$ as $F:= \{X\}$ 
Since $F$ is nonempty and $$F\cap F=F\subseteq F \cap F$$ does that mean that $X$ is a family of filters over itself?

-It seems that it is but I am unsure if the family if sets can be $X$ itself

-Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the suggesting the edit, it looks much better now.

Comment: Are you asking whether the set $\{X\}$ is a filter on $X$? The answer is yes. I'm not sure what the meaning of $F \cap F$ is. To determine whether $F$ is a filter, you want to be looking at the intersections of elements of $F$ with each other, not the intersection of $F$ with itself. We have $X \cap X = X$, so $F$ is closed under intersection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Careful with the wording: $X$ is *not* a "family of filters" over itself nor is it a filter over itself.  $F=\{X\}$ is a filter over $X$, though.  For this, you'll have to check:

- $X\in F$, which is obviously true.
- If $A,B\in F$, then $A\cap B\in F$.  This is trivial as $A$ and $B$ must both be $X$ (no other choice) and thus $A\cap B$ is again $X$.
- If $A\in F$ and $A \subseteq B \subseteq X$, then $B \in F$.  This is again trivial as $A$ can only be $X$ and thus $B$ can only be $X$.

The important thing here is to note the difference between $X$ and $\{X\}$, though.